# Using a script task in SSIS with C# language, how to convert a DTS ActiveX script that creates files and then appends the full file names

Tags: c#, ssis, activex, dts

I'm trying to convert a DTS process to SSIS and I want to convert a DTS script task that creates 3 files (only creates the file if there’s data to write to it) and then appends the full file names to a variable, which is then copied to a global variable. Since I'm new to this I would like a step by step demonstation if possible, Please, Please, Pretty Please help...Thanks. Below is an example of the DTS script that creates two instead of three files:

```
Function Main()
DIM dbConnection, rsGetFileDetails, rsGetInfo
DIM fsoFileSystem, fExportFile
DIM sGroupCode, sSequenceNumber, sFileIdentifier, FileName
DIM sLineItem, sAttachmentPaths
DIM  FileLocation
sAttachmentPaths = ""
FileLocation = DTSGlobalVariables("FileDestPath").Value

'****************************************************
'*********Connect to Database******************
'****************************************************
SET dbConnection = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
dbConnection.Provider = "sqloledb"
dbConnection.Properties("Data Source").Value = "Server"
dbConnection.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "Database"
dbConnection.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "1234"
dbConnection.Open 

'*******************************************************************
'***********GET TRACE ALERT DELIST DATA************
'*******************************************************************


SET fsoFileSystem = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
SET rsGetInfo = CreateObject( "ADODB.recordset" )


sql =  "SELECT     tblExample1.IDNumber, tblExample2.First_Name, tblExample3.Main_Name FROM         tblExample1 INNER JOIN tblExample2 ON tblExample1.IDNumber = tblExample2.Entity_ID_Number WHERE     (tblExample1.IDNumber = '2') AND (Process_Date IS NULL)"

rsGetInfo.Open sql, dbConnection
IF rsGetInfo.EOF THEN
ELSE

FileName = "MyFileName_" & Replace( Date() , "/" , "")
'//Create the file
SET fExportFile = fsoFileSystem.CreateTextFile( FileLocation & FileName & ".txt", true )
DTSGlobalVariables("FileLocation").Value =  FileLocation & FileName & ".txt"    

    rsGetInfo.MoveFirst
    DO WHILE NOT  rsGetInfo.EOF OR rsGetInfo.BOF
        sLineItem = ""
        sLineItem = rsGetInfo("IDNumber") & vbtab & rsGetDelistInfo("First_Name") & vbtab & rsGetInfo("Main_Name")

        fExportFile.Write(sLineItem & vbcrlf)

        rsGetInfo.MoveNext
    LOOP
    '// Set Attachment Path     
    sAttachmentPaths = FileLocation & FileName & ".txt" 
END IF


'*******************************************************************
'***********GET DEFAULT DELIST DATA************
'*******************************************************************


SET fsoFileSystem = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
SET rsGetInfo = CreateObject( "ADODB.recordset" )


sql =  "SELECT     Contract_No FROM      tblfunny WHERE     (funnyNumb = 1) and (Process_Date IS NULL)"

rsGetInfo.Open sql, dbConnection

IF rsGetInfo.EOF THEN
ELSE

    FileName = "MyFileName_" & Replace( Date() , "/" , "")
    '//Create the file
    SET fExportFile = fsoFileSystem.CreateTextFile(  FileLocation & FileName & ".txt", true )
    DTSGlobalVariables("FileLocation").Value =  FileLocation & FileName & ".txt"    
    rsGetInfo.MoveFirst

    DO WHILE NOT  rsGetInfo.EOF OR rsGetInfo.BOF
        sLineItem = ""
        sLineItem = rsGetInfo("Contract_No")

        fExportFile.Write(sLineItem & vbcrlf)

        rsGetInfo.MoveNext
    LOOP
    '// Set Attachment Path
    IF sAttachmentPaths = "" THEN
        sAttachmentPaths = FileLocation & FileName & ".txt"
    ELSE
        sAttachmentPaths = sAttachmentPaths & "; "& FileLocation & FileName & ".txt"
    END IF
END IF
Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success 

End Function
```

Comment: I don't want to be unhelpful, but you can't expect people to just re-write your code for you. On the other hand, if you have already tried to do it yourself but you have encountered specific coding issues or error messages then you can certainly post them so that people can provide advice.

Comment: I have added the code so that it gives a better picture. I did try a method and got the first part working but I don't exactly know how to create the second file? get default delist data...

Comment: I used a script task to Set File name, then a file system task to copy the file and a data pump, to pump the data in that file, the first one adds three coloumns to that file but the issue is that the second one uses same flat file and flat file connection and copies only one coloumn. This will append the rest of data populated in the first one and only adds one coloumn..."Contract_No". It's difficult to explain like this without screenshots but I hope its understandable...

Comment: If you are still around, what is the problem you are trying to solve? I see the steps you wish to accomplish but without knowing the full scope of the problem, I hesitate to provide an answer

Comment: Hi billinkc, I have solved the problem already and don't need a solution anymore. But thanks anyway :)